# Samsung Galaxy Note 2 configuration to enable developers mode

Tags: android

What are the lines that need to be added in `android_usb.inf`, so that I can use Samsung Galaxy Note 2 in developer's mode?
What are other changes needs to be made?

Comment: Talking about Samsung galaxy note 2

Comment: enable USB debugging mode in your gallaxy note 2 , under setting section of your device.

Comment: this is not the problem , i am not able to use device to test the applications

Comment: Enable Developer options from settings and than enable USB debugging. Now you can use your device for testing.